# React Navigation: addListener('didFocus') called over and over

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator

I'm using `react-navigation@4.0.10` in my React Native app, and I want to trigger a function whenever the user switches tabs in my tab navigator. I tried this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
        <call function>
    })
}
```

The problem is this now gets called rapidly over and over, and never stops.

Is there a better way to approach this problem?